# Accessing Windows (XP) performance counters preferably in VBScript

Tags: performance, vbscript, memory-leaks, system-monitoring

I'm testing a web application for browser memory leaks using Quick Test Professional (QTP) 9.5 and Internet Explorer 6.  PerfMon works for monitoring the memory usage over time, but its data has to be synchronized to the testing results to find out which steps trigger the  browser memory leak.  Since QTP's scripting language is VBScript, how can I get particular performance counters (in this case the "Private Bytes" in process "IExplore.exe")?

Answer (score 3):

[Don’t Panic: You Can Use Scripts to Monitor Performance](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/win2003/perfmon.mspx). Sorry about the previous line. This is the name of the article.